# c++ library to compute largest eigenvector of large sparse matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigenvector

As part of a larger problem (Spectral Clustering on images) I have to calculate the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of a matrix.
The matrix is pretty large (250000 rows/columns), symmetric and banded with ~100 entries in each row.

I actually don't even need the real eigenvector but a (relatively) crude approximation would be sufficient, which is why I suspect an iterative solver would be most suitable.

It seems ARPACK would be the weapon of choice, but having to compile it from fortran code and then wrapping a c++ interface around it seems kind of a turnoff. Are there any alternatives (preferrably fully coded in c++)?

Currently using OpenCV and Eigen3, I was even thinking about implementing my own power iteration method, but somehow I think there should be a library around that does it more efficient and stable than I ever could...

Comment: There seems to be a version for C++ ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Arpack%2B%2B

Comment: it's only a wrapper for the fortran library. true, it can work but I am on windows so its not as easy as just some apt-get magic. I was just wondering if there is anyting else that might do the job, because it seems odd to me that the only library capable of such things is a decade-old fortran lib...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a old Fortran library at all. Mostly these libraries are properly implemented and well tested and dealing with a 'timeless' subject such as Math. So even a newer version makes little sense as its just full-filling the 'not invented here' syndrome. Hence the developments of SWIG and others. Besides the fact that fortran code tends to be quite efficient.